# Sudden spike in DB connections after Aurora MySQL 2.11.1 version upgrade

Tags: mysql, upgrade, amazon-aurora

We have recently upgraded our production Aurora (MySQL) cluster from 2.10.2 to 2.11.1 as per the AWS recommendations, and once the upgrade got completed, there is a sever spike of number of DB connections observed.
The usual number of DB connections is 0-150, but after the upgrade it has suddenly risen to 600+ connections

Have someone faced this issue, your thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without much insight, do you use read replication and have you configured your application to use writer and read endpoints? Sounds as though queuing on the writer may be the issue.

Something also observed is where a change in indexing uses had become apparent and we had to make application level optimisations to define the indexing and use explicit indexes in our statements, such as USE INDEX('indexname'). Seemed after the upgrade the DB was using suboptimal indexing strategies (which may optimise naturally over time but a pain in the short term)

Comment: We use separate reader and writer end points. Issue is mostly with INSERTS on writer.